# How to solve this polynomial congruence

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I want to solve this polynomial congruence with details. $$x^7-14x-2\equiv0 \mod 1323$$ Any help would be appreciate. Thank you.

Comment: We have $1323=3^3\cdot7^2$, so it looks like you will be using Chinese Remainder Theorem. It also looks like Hensel lifting a solution modulo $p$ to a solution modulo $p^k$ for a prime $p$ will come in handy. Mind you, modulo $7$ Hensel won't help here for the derivative vanishes modulo $7$. How much time you want to spend on this? I mean bruteforcing it modulo 49 and modulo 27 is feasible for even pencil&paper work, but you won't mind shortcuts, do you?

Comment: what do you mean by shortcut? are there any short method?